# Django/Python Exceptions not working?

Tags: python, django, exception

I'm trying to work out an exception problem I've been having with django: I have a view with the following call with an url `http://someurl.com/?items=1,2,3`. I want to deal with cases where `?items=` or `?items=somthing_bs`. When I always get the error: local variable `'apps'` referenced before assignment. Shouldn't it catch all the exceptions and errors that come it's way in the try clause? My code:

```
 def my_view(request):
    if request.GET.get('mashpoint'):
        try:
            item_ids = request.GET.get('mashpoint')
            item_ids = item_ids.split(',')
            apps = mpApp.objects.filter(mpitem__pk__in=item_ids).distinct()
            return render_to_response(template_name,context_instance=RequestContext(request,{'apps':apps,'item_ids':','.join(item_ids)}))
        except:
            return render_to_response(template_name,context_instance=RequestContext(request,{}))
    return render_to_response(template_name,context_instance=RequestContext(request,{}))
```

Comment: Can you edit your post to fix the indentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last `render_to_response` is outside the `if` block above it. So in cases where there's no `items` key in `GET` or the `items` key is empty (`/path/?items=`), `apps` is undefined.

It would be better to use:

```
if request.GET.has_key('items'):
```

Comment: Yes, that's it.. I also revised the code the last bit had no point! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably in the second `render_to_response` statement. `apps` is being used when no value has been assigned to it.

Note: I'm assumming that that statement isn't included in the `if` statement above (as pointed out by Rob Wouters, indentation doesn't seem to be correct). Anyway, you can confirm by looking at the line number the error is being reported.

Answer (score 0):

Move the second call to `render_to_response` inside the `try` block, it has no point where it is now, if the `if` block structure is like you posted. Otherwise you'll always get that error, since it's not a runtime error.